# Roll-up data from a restricted subsite to parent site

Tags: aggregation

One of my Site Owners has requested a feature to roll-up data from a restricted list.

The list is located in a restricted subsite. They want a short summary to roll-up to the parent site. 
They don´t want the users to be able to see the whole item details, only the summary.

Please, is this possible? Out of the box? SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 0):

If the item itself is restricted for other users (i.e. they don't even have read permission), it wouldn't help. Users can only see items where they have at least "restricted read" permission rights.

To accomplish this, you need to add another custom list, move the summary to the other list and use a lookup column in place of the summary of the original list.

It's not possible to set permission on columns in SharePoint.

Comment: So I will need to make a new custom list in the subsite, with one column with lookup

Comment: once I have done that, how will I make it visible in the parent site?

Comment: You can use a Content Search Web Part, if you have SharePoint 2013/2016 Enterprise edition

Comment: Ok, I will try. Is there a better/easier way to do it in SharePoint Designer? To minimize the administration of the lists. So it all will be automatically updated as soon as it´s updated in the original list (in the subsite)

Comment: It depends. I don't trust SharePoint Destroyer(!) that much and like to work things out in a browser. Often that gives better result. But if your comfortable with SharePoint Designer, you should use that tool.